# Understanding ILIKE ANY element of an array - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to select all the lines in a table (let's call it `mytable`) for which the value in a given column (let's call it `mycolumn`) is **not** equal to 'A' and **not** equal to 'S'.

So I tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn NOT ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['A','S'])
```

I prefer the use of `ILIKE` instead of the use of `=` to test string equalities because the values 'A' and 'S' may come in lower-case in my data, so I want the values 's' and 'a' to be excluded as well.

Strangely enough, the query above did return some lines for which the value inside `mycolumn` was equal to 'A'. I was very surprised.

Therefore, to understand what was happening I tried to carry out a very simple logical test:

```
SELECT ('A' ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['A','S'])) as logical_test ;
```

The statement above returns TRUE, which was expected.

But the following statement also returns TRUE and this is where I'm lost:

```
SELECT ('A' NOT ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['A','S'])) as logical_test ;
```

Could someone explain why `'A' NOT ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['A','S'])` is considered TRUE by PostgreSQL?

Comment: OK, so if I understand your comment, I have to put the NOT before the statement? Indeed, NOT 'A' ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['A','S']) did return FALSE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The result of the ANY comparison is true if at least one element from the array qualifies for the condition.

As `'S'` is different from `'A'` the result of `ANY` is true (because at least *one* element was different).

You are looking for the `ALL` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mycolumn NOT ILIKE ALL(ARRAY['A','S'])
```

Comment: So that's a mathematical set problem. I took the union of some logical statements instead of taking the intersection. Thanks.

Comment: `NOT` inverts the logic. So `ANY` becomes `ALL` and vice versa

Comment: It's a little confusing because when inverting the `IN` operator, this is automatically taken care of.