# How to request by condition on column "where value likes (or contains) one of strings (or regex) inside specific array?

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, where-clause, query-builder

I need to retrieve all record with specific column contains, equals, or likes one of words inside specific array.

I am talking about "contains" because in the database, some values are in plural, and other singular; like : "dog" and "dogs".

So I will provide an array as ['dog', 'cat',...] and I will make search on column values containing "dog" or "dogs", "cat" or "cats".

I can use whereIn but this does not cover plural nouns.

I think to associate another condition found here: [Understanding ILIKE ANY element of an array - postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557830/understanding-ilike-any-element-of-an-array-postgresql) . So I am trying:

```
    ->where(function($q) use ($animals) {
    $q->whereIn('name', $animals)
    ->orWhere('name', 'ilike ALL(', '%' . $animals . '%)');
    })
```

but it is not working obviously.
Could you please help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually writing the list of items that should match to their plurals, can you just add the words to the array?  IE:

```
['cat', 'cats', 'dog', 'dogs']; // etc
```

However, if you need to work with a dynamic list that must include plurals to match in your database, probably easiest is to loop through the array and add the plurals using the [String helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-plural) from **Laravel**:

```
 $plurals = [];
 foreach ($animals as $animal){
     $plurals[] = Str::plural($animal);
 }
```

Then merge the arrays (`$animals` and `$plurals`) into one, and you can do a single `whereIn('name', $animalsMerged)` on the query.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but Str::plural works only for english language. Also, the plural is just an example. sometimes the database contains other words / expressions with one of these word like "dogs (australian shepherd)". so I need to check how to retrieve this expression with my query. because it contains "dog"

Comment: Yes, it won't work for non-English words.  And definitely not for subsets like Australian shepherd.  You didn't ask that in the question though, so I didn't think the parameters were that stringent.  I don't know how much choice you have in this other than to create a dictionary.   If you don't have **any** control over the categories of what's coming in, this may not be reasonably possible.  If the categories are limited, then a manual dictionary might be your only choice.